Waiting for the app to invoke SSLContext.init()
i'm using Genymotion as Android 10 emulator, BurpSuite and the latest verion of frida server in order to bypass SSL pinning.
this is not the first time I do that but it doesn't work. I thought I have missed a step but I did everything right (I tried 3 times) but all I get is this:
     ____
    / _  |   Frida 16.2.1 - A world-class dynamic instrumentation toolkit
   | (_| |
    > _  |   Commands:
   /_/ |_|       help      -> Displays the help system
   . . . .       object?   -> Display information about 'object'
   . . . .       exit/quit -> Exit
   . . . .
   . . . .   More info at https://frida.re/docs/home/
   . . . .
   . . . .   Connected to Nexus 4 (id=127.0.0.1:6555)
Spawned `my_binary`. Resuming main thread!                   
[Nexus 4::my_binary ]->
[.] Cert Pinning Bypass/Re-Pinning
[+] Loading our CA...
[o] Our CA Info: CN=PortSwigger CA, OU=PortSwigger CA, O=PortSwigger, L=PortSwigger, ST=PortSwigger, C=PortSwigger
[+] Creating a KeyStore for our CA...
[+] Creating a TrustManager that trusts the CA in our KeyStore...
[+] Our TrustManager is ready...
[+] Hijacking SSLContext methods now...
[-] Waiting for the app to invoke SSLContext.init()...


and it get stuck there forever.
Edit:
I also tried with another application where it worked fine, but this specific application that I want to work on seems to have something that prevents it from working. Does anyone knows what could be the reason?
Edit 2: I tried with HttpToolKit and this is what prompted:

Certificate rejected for connection to name_of_server.org


The frida bypassing SSL scripts each only intercept the SSL library they have been written for. If an app uses a totally different SSL library or a totally different runtime then those scripts will not work. Decompile the app using Jadx-Gui, Ghidra, Hopper, IDA, ... to see what is going on.
